# How to bind error messages sent by Django in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, error-handling

My problem is I would like to bind the error messages sent by a Django api after a POST or GET with my scope in Angularjs to display it in the right field in my DOM.

For example:

```
$scope.location.save(params,
            function(response) {
                console.log('Success');
            },
            function (result) {
                    //bind function
                }
            }
        );
```

Error message sent by Django :

```
{
data: {
    rule: {
        frequency: [{
            0: "'' n'est pas un choix valide."
        }]

    }
}
error: true
status: 400
statusText: "BAD REQUEST"
```

}

I don't know if there is something to do with the BACK response form Django or in FRONT in Angularjs. (I'm a front dev, no experience with Django)
So it would be GREAT to bind this error response with the corresponding scope(field). In this case, $scope.location.rule.frequency. So if anyone has an idea to do that simply without writing a huge error function which take all the different cases into consideration. THX for your help.

Comment: Can't you just ng-repeat over the elements in the frequency array?

Comment: In fact, I've put 'data.rule.frequency' in the example, but it could be also 'data.title' or 'data.description'. So thx, but I don't think ng-repeat could be a valuable solution. I know that when I use pure Django forms, and there are errors, the value of each fields are directly modified with the error value, the same value sent in the response. I just want the same behavior.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using django-rest? you could probably over ride the default exception handlers provided to a custom one as described here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/

Comment: thx, I'll look on this side.